# Elasticsearch _search not providing results

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I'm trying to return all name fields and count fields from my index however when I try to search for data no data is returned (as shown in last code stub). I definitely have data in my index. What am I doing wrong in my _search command?

My mappings:

```
PUT /visual
{
  "mappings": {
     "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {"type": "date"},
        "name": {
           "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                 "keyword" : {
                     "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "count": {"type": "integer"},
        "err": {"type": "integer"},
        "delta1": {"type": "integer"},
        "str_list": {"type": "text"}
     }
  }
}
```

My search command where I have tried to return the name field, count field and timestamp:

```
POST visual/_search

{
  "query":{
    "range":{
      "order_date":{
        "gte":"now-80d"
      }
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
      "names":{
        "terms":{"field":"name.keyword"},
    "aggs": {
      "counts":{
        "terms":{"field":"count"},
    "aggs": {
        "time_buckets": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "fixed_interval": "1h",
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": "now-80d"
            },
          "min_doc_count": 0
          }
        }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    },"size":100

}
```

The Response where no data has been returned:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "names" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any `order_date` field in your mapping. You might want to use `@timestamp` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your range query, you're using the field `order_field`, which doesn't exist given your mappings. So maybe using `@timestamp` will already solve the problem?

```
"query":{
    "range":{
      "@timestamp":{
        "gte":"now-80d"
      }
    }
  }
```

Check the [range query doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/query-dsl-range-query.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks that returns data however it returns every field instead of just name, count and timestamp?

Comment: Yes, because there's no filtering on the fields in the query.
You could e.g. add _source filtering to your query, like:
```"_source": ["name", "count", "@timestamp"]```

Check [Retrieve selected fields from a search Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/search-fields.html) for more information.